# Paloma gem preventing header-only response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers, rubygems, partial-views

Our application uses the [Paloma gem](https://github.com/kbparagua/paloma) to oversee JavaScript execution for each request. That normally works great, until you try to do a header-only response. For example, here's the code for the update action in our controller:

```
class EmployeesController < InternalController

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      format.any do
        head :ok
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Pretty simple. It should not need to use any views or templates to generate this response. Right? Then Paloma gets involved... and instead of a nice, simple HTTP 200 OK we get an `ActionView::MissingTemplate` exception raised with the following error message and trace:

```
Missing partial paloma/callback_hook with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:all], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :slim, :coffee, :haml, :rabl]}.
Searched in: * "/Users/<username>/Development/<app name>/app/views" * "/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jasminerice-0.0.10/app/views" * "/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/paloma-2.0.1/app/views" * "/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/kaminari-0.14.1/app/views" * "/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.2.3/app/views" * "/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/paloma-2.0.1/app/views"
Backtrace:
  /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/path_set.rb:58:in `find'
  /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:109:in `find'
  /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `find_template'
  /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:333:in `find_partial'
  /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:222:in `render'
  /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:41:in `render_partial'
  /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:15:in `render'
  /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:24:in `render'
  /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/haml-4.0.0/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:12:in `render_with_haml'
  /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/paloma-2.0.1/lib/paloma/action_controller_filters.rb:23:in `update_callback'
  ...
  (further lines snipped)
```

Confounding the matter is the fact that, when I go and look in the installed gem, the partial that it's looking for is right there in all its glory, so there doesn't seem to be any reason why Rails shouldn't have been able to find it:

```
Maple:~ <username>$ ls -l /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/paloma-2.0.1/app/views/paloma
total 8
-rw-rw-r--  1 <username>  staff  1323 Mar 11 09:10 _callback_hook.html.erb
```

This does not occur for other requests which return an HTTP status of 200 as well as a response body, it only occurs for header-only responses via Rails' `head` method.

Have I found a bug in the Paloma gem? Or a bug in Rails? Or is there something that I should be adjusting to allow the view to be found? Why the heck is Rails searching for a view to generate a header-only response in the first place? Any help or suggestions that anyone can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you want Paloma not to execute in a specific Rails Controller
>   action you need to pass false as the Paloma parameter.
>
> ```
> def edit
>   @user = User.find params[:id]
>   js false
> end
> ```

https://github.com/kbparagua/paloma#preventing-paloma-execution

Comment: Chris, that is what I wound up doing in the end. (It's been a while since I asked this question -- I don't even work for the same company anymore!) However, I do strongly feel that Paloma should be able to detect responses for which executing doesn't make any sense -- such as header-only responses -- and turn itself off without needing `js false`. Perhaps someday I'll write and submit a PR for that. Thanks!